# Authentication for github on Dockerfile

Tags: authentication, github, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile I want to clone a repo from github. To achieve that I applied the following command to my Dockerfile:

`RUN git clone -b docker https://<pat-token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<mygithubaccount>/<repository.git> /myfolder`

*Of course, the phrases in square brackets are placeholders.*

When I build the image from my Dockerfile I can read authentication error in the output:

> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
> remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.

I assume that is something around my authentication string. Maybe I cannot use a personal access token?
How do I correctly authenticate against github in my Dockerfile?

Comment: OT: these are called "angle brackets", square brackets are [ and ]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - I've had a type in the token